# phpmyadmin - change export rights for user

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, rights

is there way to change export rights for user in phpMyAdmin for certain column in table? Specifically not allow to export this particular column.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I dont think so.

But there are some rights so user not able to see those tables or database. you can change setting from user option available in phpmyadmin.

[image]